# how to wait for an observable but return the previous observable result in rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following sequence to execute:

1. read a small piece of data
2. clear the data storage
3. re-save the small piece of data from (1)

Each operation is handled by a method that returns an `Observable`. Here is the sequence I came up with:

```js
this.storage.get('key').pipe(
  switchMap((x) => this.storage.clear().pipe(map(()=>x))),
  switchMap((x) => this.set('key', x)
);
```

the repeated use of `switchMap()` feels dirty. This sequence does work, but I was wondering if there is a simplification.

I tried using `concat()` to start, but it emits each value individually. I don't think I can use `merge` because it starts each observable in parallel and I obviously don't want the `.clear()` to execute while I am executing either `.get()` or `.set()`.

What operator or create function could I be using that would:

- start the first Observable
- wait until the first Observable to start the 2nd one
- then return an array (or a map) of both results

*or* is there a simplification for the double call to `switchMap()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [delayWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delaywhen)

```
this.storage.get('key').pipe(
  delayWhen(() => this.storage.clear()),
  switchMap((x) => this.set('key', x))
);
```

Comment: I knew there was a simplification! I have to start making a recipe book with those things...

Comment: Aren't you losing the value returned by `storage.get()` here?

Comment: Well, I guess not!  Normally, with the pipeable operators, the return from a previous will be pushed into the following one, however after looking at the source for [`delayWhen`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delayWhen.ts#L89), I can see that it internally maps back to the value it received (and doesn't emit the emissions from its source observable). TIL.